# Is there anyway to set a variable value once when I self submit to itself

Tags: php

I am trying to make this simple guess number in PHP. The problem is that once I submit this form to myself, the **$number** variable will be randomized again instead of keeping the previous values. Is there anyway to kept it the same?

```
<?php
    $run_once = true;
    $number = 10;
    $user_input = 1;
    $display_answer = "";

    function seedRandNumber() {
        srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
        $num = rand(1, 25);
        return $num;
    }

    if ($run_once) {
        $number = seedRandNumber();
        $run_once = false;
    }

    function answer($input) {
        $num = $GLOBALS['number'];
        if ($input == $num) {
           return "You guess it right";
        } else if ($input > $num) {
            return "it is a lower number";
        } else {
            return "it is a high number";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST["number"])) {
        $user_input = $_POST["number"];
        $display_answer = answer($_POST["number"]);
    }

    if (isset($_POST["newgame"])) {
        $number = seedRandNumber();
    }

    ?>

    <h1>Guess Number</h1>

<p1>Please enter a number between 1 and 25</p1>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"> 
    Number: <input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo $user_input; ?>"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
    <p2><?php echo $display_answer; ?></p2><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="newgame" value="New Game">
</form>
```

Comment: or write it it to db\file

Comment: Unless this is an educational thing, I kind of don't see the point of using PHP for a simple number guessing game.  JavaScript would get the job done without having to worry about posts and sessions and stuff.

Comment: @AndrewNee if the number to be guessed was stored in JS, then it would be pretty easy to cheat.

Comment: What do you mean?  Like a user could get access to the contents of a JS variable?  Even if so, what do they get out of cheating on a little web game?  Unless prizes are offered or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your number in the session, then only create a new one when required:

```
start_session();

if(!isset($_SESSION['number']) || isset($_POST['newgame'])) {
    $number = seedRandNumber();
    $_SESSION['number'] = $number;
}
else {
    $number = $_SESSION['number'];
}
```

You need to put this at the start of your program.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about session.